# VBA use of ActiveCell.Offset gives Run-time error 9 subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba, subscript

This is my first post, so please bear with me.
I am currently learning VBA coding for excel and i am trying to read a .csv file and interpret it.
I do however get an error '9'(subscript out of range) when i run the script, and though the code still works, I need to get rid of it.
The code is as follows :

```
Sub OpenTextFile() 
Worksheets("Ark1").ChartObjects.Delete
Close #1
Call chart


Dim path As String
path = "C:\hello"

Dim file As String
file = Range("C1").Value


Dim filetype As String
filetype = ".csv"

Dim FilePath As String
FilePath = path & file & filetype


Open FilePath For Input As #1 

row_number = 0

Do Until EOF(1)   

     Line Input #1, LineFromFile

     LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, ";")

     ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 1).Value = LineItems(2) <-Debug tells me problem is here
     ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 0).Value = LineItems(1)

     row_number = row_number + 1

Loop

Close #1
End Sub

Private Sub chart() 
Range("A1:A96").Select 
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
End Sub
```

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 
   Call OpenTextFile
   End Sub

Now i keep getting errors in my   "ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 1).Value = LineItems(2)" ( and i suspect the same will happen to the next line)

I cant find any solution to my problem as the EOF function in my Do Loop should define an end to the loop, and the data is copied in just fine. 
If it helps, I have used this guide to write the code : http://www.homeandlearn.org/open_a_text_file_in_vba.html
- In advance, thanks! :)

Comment: You can't offset from row 0.

Comment: @tbur: you can it just means stay in the same row

Comment: You need to make sure that `LineItems` returns an array otherwise that will create an error. Also make sure that the size is correct. What you can do is add watch on `LineItems` and also a break point so you can monitor what's happening on the variable. Also, it'd be best to load all the lines in one go in an array variable then iterate.

Comment: @bernie: The code literally starts at row 0. It doesn't matter if you offset from there, it's still going to error.

Comment: @tbur: ah, yes, you make a good point.

Comment: Can i be that i use EOF(1) ? the complier does not know how much memory to allocate on the stack if i cant tell it how long the file is?

Comment: @L42 : Can you perhaps help me a bit ? I have tried for at couple of hours to make the changes you suggested, but with no success..
Can the problem be that the program in compile time does not know how much memory to allocate, as the files i am loading in has different sizes?